# Is my local variable a reference to my external collection and does locking lock the original?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, locking

I have two classes, one of which contains a list which should always be synchronised but for which I want to use an accessor.

```
class MyObject {
     private List<Thing> things = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
     public List<Thing> getThings() { return things; }
}
```

In another class (an Android activity)  I want to *safely* iterate over the collection

```
class MyActivity {

     private void someMethod() {
         List<Thing> localThings = myObjectInstance.getThings();
         //we have to manually synchronise when iterating synchronizedList
         synchronized(localThings) {
             for (Thing thing : localThings) {
                 //do something to a thing
             }
         }
     }

}
```

My question is, what is happening in my block of code above? is my `localThings` variable a pointer to the same collection as `MyObject::things` or have I created a new collection (in which case there's no need for me to synchronise). If it's the former am I keeping it threadsafe by doing this (is the original collection locked)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, what is happening in my block of code above? is my
>   localThings variable a pointer to the same collection as
>   MyObject::things

Yes.  You `return things`, where `things` is a reference.  The caller receives a copy of the reference, which necessarily refers to the same object.

> or have I created a new collection (in which case
>   there's no need for me to synchronise).

No, but you *could* create and return a new `List`:

```
return new ArrayList<Thing>(things);
```

However, you probably need to synchronize on `things` to safely initialize the copy that way.  If you do not need to be able to change the size of the copy then you could get around the need for external synchronization like this:

```
return Arrays.asList(things.toArray(new Thing[0]));
```

> If it's the former am I
>   keeping it threadsafe by doing this (is the original collection
>   locked)?

Given that the collection referenced by `localThings` is a synchronized list wrapper provided by `Collections.synchronizedList()` and that you are iterating over it inside a block synchronized on that object, no other thread will be able to invoke any of that list's methods until control leaves the synchronized block.  This level of mutual exclusion is necessary if it would otherwise be possible for a different thread to add elements to or remove elements from the list while the iteration is proceeding, and it is sufficient to protect against that.

Comment: Excellent, you answered everything I needed. Thank you (I was just worried about synchronising only on a copy by accident)